# What is the difference between Script and ScriptWithList?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server SMO, what is the difference between `Scripter.Script` and `Scripter.ScriptWithList`?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the return value.
Script method returns a StringCollection object value that specifies the Tranasact-SQL scripts for the list of objects. Reference Scripter.Script method [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms209761%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
The ScriptWithList method returns a SqlSmoObject object array value that specifies the list of objects to be scripted. Reference Scripter.ScriptWitList [2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms209760%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Except that just appears to be a documentation error, since that exact description is applied to the input parameter also, and the return types for both are `StringCollection`.

Comment: You see why I am confused. They have the same input and output data types, so what exactly is different with the processing?

Comment: I must be missing something you're seeing.  The docs say the Script method returns a StringCollection while the ScriptWithList returns a SQLSmoObject. At least that's what I see in the links in the answer.  The ScriptWithList method also has an extra overload (DependencyCollection) that doesn't exist in the Script method.

Comment: You've not provided *any* explanation on how these two methods are different (caveat: I've not done so either). All you've provided is a textual difference in the documentation - and one that appears to exist by error rather than by purpose.

Comment: I'd say there is a difference between getting back a StringCollection object and a SqlSmoObject.  Just look at the methods and properties of each.  But since I don't want to get into a battle over this I'll stop at this comment.

Comment: Follow your *own* link number 2. Look under return type. "Type:  [System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection.aspx)". Yes, the second line says something different, but as I say, that's a documentation bug. I've just loaded up the `Scripter` class and confirmed that all of the callable `Script` and `ScriptWithList` methods return `StringCollection`. (there are private/internal methods that return `IEnumerable<string>`, but that's not relevant here)

Comment: So what is the difference?